# error - Error: Must initialize before using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, blockchain

I have just created a fresh Next app, and after adding line no. 6, I'm getting error. Why?

[image]

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import { useConnectWallet, useSetChain, useWallets } from "@web3-onboard/react";

const Home = () => {
  const [{ wallet }, connect, disconnect] = useConnectWallet();
  const [{ chains, connectedChain, settingChain }, setChain] = useSetChain();
  const connectedWallets = useWallets();
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>New - emax</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <p>Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a public URL with Vercel.</p>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you add your code to sandbox?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, **error messages**, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 (Although your title has the error message, it *looks* like a summary of it [though I think it's actually the whole message]. It's better to put the full copy-and-pasted error in the question, marked up as a quote, so we know it's verbatim.)

Comment: `const [first, setfirst] = useState(null);` it is also showing the same error

Comment: Turned up with a very basic web search: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@web3-onboard/core#Initialization *"Onboard needs to be initialized with an options object before the API can be used:"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import and call the **init** function from `@web3-onboard/react` before any hooks (eg. `useConnectWallet()`) can be used.

```
import {
  init,
  useConnectWallet,
  useSetChain,
  useWallets
} from '@web3-onboard/react'
```

[image: From official doc]

Check here for exact example - https://socket.dev/npm/package/@web3-onboard/react

Comment: for a moment, let's forget this. 
`const [first, setfirst] = useState(null);`
it is also showing same error.

Comment: How would you handle this

Comment: I believe it's happening because of the ```@web3-onboard/react``` import. It must be a mandatory requirement to use ```init``` function before using any kind of hook in order to work with ```@web3-onboard/react``` .

Comment: thankyou ankit saxena for your help

Answer (score 1):

first call init look like this sample :

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  init,
  useConnectWallet,
  useSetChain,
  useWallets
} from '@web3-onboard/react'
import injectedModule from '@web3-onboard/injected-wallets'
import trezorModule from '@web3-onboard/trezor'
import ledgerModule from '@web3-onboard/ledger'
import walletConnectModule from '@web3-onboard/walletconnect'
import walletLinkModule from '@web3-onboard/walletlink'
import portisModule from '@web3-onboard/portis'
import fortmaticModule from '@web3-onboard/fortmatic'
import torusModule from '@web3-onboard/torus'
import keepkeyModule from '@web3-onboard/keepkey'

const injected = injectedModule()
const walletLink = walletLinkModule()
const walletConnect = walletConnectModule()

const portis = portisModule({
  apiKey: 'b2b7586f-2b1e-4c30-a7fb-c2d1533b153b'
})

const fortmatic = fortmaticModule({
  apiKey: 'pk_test_886ADCAB855632AA'
})

const torus = torusModule()
const ledger = ledgerModule()
const keepkey = keepkeyModule()

const trezorOptions = {
  email: 'test@test.com',
  appUrl: 'https://www.blocknative.com'
}

const trezor = trezorModule(trezorOptions)

const web3Onboard = init({
  wallets: [
    ledger,
    trezor,
    walletConnect,
    keepkey,
    walletLink,
    injected,
    fortmatic,
    portis,
    torus
  ],
  chains: [
    {
      id: '0x1',
      token: 'ETH',
      label: 'Ethereum Mainnet',
      rpcUrl: 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/ababf9851fd845d0a167825f97eeb12b'
    },
    {
      id: '0x3',
      token: 'tROP',
      label: 'Ethereum Ropsten Testnet',
      rpcUrl: 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/ababf9851fd845d0a167825f97eeb12b'
    },
    {
      id: '0x4',
      token: 'rETH',
      label: 'Ethereum Rinkeby Testnet',
      rpcUrl: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/ababf9851fd845d0a167825f97eeb12b'
    },
    {
      id: '0x89',
      token: 'MATIC',
      label: 'Matic Mainnet',
      rpcUrl: 'https://matic-mainnet.chainstacklabs.com'
    }
  ],
  appMetadata: {
    name: 'Blocknative',
    icon: '<svg><svg/>',
    description: 'Demo app for Onboard V2',
    recommendedInjectedWallets: [
      { name: 'MetaMask', url: 'https://metamask.io' },
      { name: 'Coinbase', url: 'https://wallet.coinbase.com/' }
    ]
  }
})

function App() {
  const [{ wallet, connecting }, connect, disconnect] = useConnectWallet()
  const [{ chains, connectedChain, settingChain }, setChain] = useSetChain()
  const connectedWallets = useWallets()

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => connect()}>
        {connecting ? 'connecting' : 'connect'}
      </button>
      {wallet && (
        <div>
          <label>Switch Chain</label>
          {settingChain ? (
            <span>Switching chain...</span>
          ) : (
            <select
              onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
                console.log('onChange called') || setChain({ chainId: value })
              }
              value={connectedChain.id}
            >
              {chains.map(({ id, label }) => {
                return <option value={id}>{label}</option>
              })}
            </select>
          )}
          <button onClick={() => disconnect(wallet)}>
            Disconnect Wallet
          </button>
        </div>
      )}

      {connectedWallets.map(({ label, accounts }) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>{label}</div>
            <div>Accounts: {JSON.stringify(accounts, null, 2)}</div>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

see [here](https://docs.blocknative.com/onboard/react-hooks)

Comment: thanks buddy but answer is exactly same as previous one